# Why can't I save a new measurement created in my tabular model in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, powerbi, sql-server-2019, ssas-tabular, power-bi-report-server

I am currently working with a BI environment that was developed by a service provider for my company. The infrastructure uses SQL Server 2019 (developer edition) and employs a BI architecture that involves creating a DWH database using the Extract Load Transform (ELT) process from SSIS packages. This database feeds into my tabular model on Visual Studio 2019. The Workspace Server (named localhost) is a workspace instance that contains the datamart  and was also created on the same computer. Reports are built using Power BI connected to the server localhot, which the company accesses via Power BI services. The reports are automatically updated every day.

[image: AchitectureBI]

Recently, I needed to make some changes to the report, including creating a new Flow W% measure that divides Flow W and Flow W-1, both of which were already created on the cube. I created the measure in the tabular model project and successfully deployed it. However, when I tried to save my changes in the project directory, I received an error message, even though I had selected the same project and asked to replace it.Moreover i was not able to retrieve my measure on PowerBI services.

[image: the measurecreated]
[image: measuredisappear]
[image: Access Denied for saving]

I need some help regarding my tabular model. I made some modifications to it but none of them are getting saved. As a workaround, I created a new template to save the changes. However, when I open the template, it appears to be empty.

I tried creating a measurement on PowerBI Desktop but it seems to be outdated compared to the version available on PowerBI services. There are too many changes to make and i was not able to know all of them.

Can you please guide me on how to modify the cube so that I can retrieve the measure directly from PowerBI services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service provider to your company has done a lot of questionable things that need to be corrected. I'm assuming you are new to these tools, so I apologize if I'm telling you anything you already know.

First off, you mention Developer Edition. "It is a free edition of SQL Server for developers and/or testers. This SQL Server edition is used for non-production environments".[1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7201/sql-server-developer-edition-download-install-get-started/) If you are publishing reports built off this data, you need a paid licensed version. IT was OK to do a proof of concept using Developer Edition, but it needs to be moved to production.

Second, when you use this for a production environment, SQL **Sevrer** should be installed on a **server**, not on your computer. Visual Studio, SSMS, and Power BI should be accessing the server and not localhost. To do your development, you should be working from your computer and connect to the server. There is no need to remotely connect to a server to do your development.

When you set up the project in Visual Studio, you have the option of setting up the Development Workspace on a server (typically the same server where you will deploy your model) or on your workstation (the "Integrated workspace" option). I prefer to always use the server. More on that shortly.

[image]

You can check which you are using by clicking on **Model.bim** in the **Solution Explorer** pane, then scroll down and check the settings shown below. **Workspace Server** is the server name for temporary model created while you are making changes. **Workspace Database** is the database name for this temporary model, and is in the format of "ProdDBname_userid_GUID". The default sets the **Workspace Retention** to "Unload from memory". This is helpful because 1) it doesn't take memory away from your production models, and 2) you can view the server from SSMS and see who is working on a model.

[image]

So in your screenshot, I see a production model, DM_NAPS, and 2 development instances, one for user "pbi" and one for "pbiv2". Normally I would expect this to be your username and not an application account like these, which leads me to believe this is the cause of your error message.

[image]

In English, I read the error as "Access to the access path  'D:\Data…' is denied." (Please always paste in error messages as text and not as images, especially in another language! This is probably why no one has responded to your post yet.) This is just a permissions error to the D drive for some account. My guess is you are somehow using your user account and an application account, and one of the 2 accounts does not have access to this drive. I don't develop this way, so I don't know how you have this set up, but that's what you should look into.

In my experience, only one person should be editing a model at a time, or user **pbi** will overwrite user **pbiv2**'s changes when they deploy. The fact that there are 2 dev versions out there at the same time is something that normally shouldn't happen. I am the only developer of my models, so I'm not the best person to give advice here, but you need to be aware of who all is working on this model at the same. Maybe the access error is because someone else has the project open.

The Deployment looks like it was successful (again, please paste messages as text, especially if not in English). You should check your settings to confirm where it was deployed, and make sure Power BI is pointing at that same server. Go to **Project > Properties** and check the setting for **Server**. Then check that Power BI is using this same server and your measures should be there, though depending on how your connected from Power BI, you may need to do a refresh.

[image]

You can also check your measures from SSMS by right clicking the database and selecting **New Query > MDX** and then using the command `select * from $SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_MEASURES WHERE [Name] = 'your_measure_name';` (Note that LIKE is not supported here.)

[image]

I hope something in there helped and sorry if I'm over-explaining anything!

Comment: Your detailed answer has shed more light on other issues for me, as I am a beginner in SQL Server tools. The SQL Server tools, and Power BI are  all installed on the server. I develop from my computer and connect to the server using the workspace server that Power BI also uses. However, the database server is set up under the user "pbiv2 development." From my research, it seems that the development was first done on the "pbi" account and then moved to the "pbv2" account, which is currently being used. I  checked the cube with your command, but unfortunately, I cannot seem to find my measure.

Comment: So that sounds like the pbiv2 account doesn't have access to the d: drive on the server. If pbiv2 is a server admin, you can probably use that account to get access just by browsing the folder from Windows Explorer. Otherwise you will likely need a server admin to grant access to this account.

There is no need to remote into the server to do your development in most cases. You should just install Visual Studio 2022 with the SQL Server Data Tools extensions on your computer and work from there. Our security team discourages direct server access except when absolutely necessary.

Comment: Could you please provide me with a link that contains more information about on how don't acces the server to develop?

Comment: Here's a bunch of links.
Here's creating a model from scratch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tutorial-tabular-1400/as-lesson-1-create-a-new-tabular-model-project?view=asallproducts-allversions 
It walks through creating it using an integrated workspace, though I prefer the Workspace server option as mentioned above. This link shows the deploy to the server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tutorial-tabular-1400/as-lesson-13-deploy?view=asallproducts-allversions, which is necessary when using the Integrated server option.

Comment: Another common template is "Import from Server (Tabular)". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tabular-models/import-from-analysis-services-ssas-tabular?view=asallproducts-allversions You use this from your computer to create the files necessary to make changes to an existing model if you can't find where they are stored, or if they are on the server and you want to start developing on your computer.

Comment: I don't know that there is any specific link that advises to run Visual Studio on your workstation and not the server. You can tell by the templates that this is the intended method, but you really can do either way. Server best practices would say to avoid logging on to the server because you can do more damage from there, use more server resources, more security risk, etc. From your workstation you also have the flexibility to deploy to multiple servers (Dev, QA, Prod, etc.) which is a common practice for larger models.

Comment: I develop from my workstation primarily because our shop does password vaulting, has a short timeout for inactivity, and doesn't allow Internet browser use from the server. It is a huge hassle to do any development on the server.